# Timer (The Constructor timer(int, actionlistener) is undefined

Tags: java, swing, timer

I've been looking at some other threads and different ways to go about this and I keep getting the same error. I left out the package and imports. I was using Thread but, I read you shouldn't use them for GUI.

```
public class Game extends JPanel{

Player player = new Player(this);

public Game(){
    addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
            player.keyReleased(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            player.keyPressed(e);
        }
    });
}

public void move(){
    player.move();
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    player.paint(g2d);
}

public void timer1(){
     int delay = 10; //milliseconds
      ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           System.out.println("Running");
          }
      };
      new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();;

Thread.sleep(10);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, Exception{
    int Width = 800;
    int Height = 400;
    Game game = new Game();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("quest Kings");
    frame.setSize(Width, Height);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setResizable(false);


    //What to do after the program starts
    while(true){
        game.move();
        game.repaint();
        game.timer1();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have not included the critical import statements with your code. Please avoid doing this in the future as they're very important.

Comment: `public void paint(Graphics g){ super.paint(g);` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ super.paintComponent(g);`

Answer (score 5):

You've imported the wrong Timer or have not imported any Timer. Make sure that your import statements include

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
```

Note that the `java.util.Timer` import doesn't count. This is why it is critical for you to include your imports with your question.

Comment: I swear it's always the little things I seem to keep making errors on lol. Thank you for the help.